# How can I run prototype.js version 1.7+ I need to

Tags: prototype-js

I need to run prototype.js version 1.7 or above and I have version 1.6.0.3 installed.
When I run version 1.7+ I can not see images for products in my admin section making it impossible to use. I have Magento community version 1.5.1

The reason I need to run version 1.7+ is because I want to use JW video player with Chromecast support - when I do on prototype.js 1.6.0.3 Chromecast on IOS does not work ( works on flash for desktop).
When I run 1.7+ prototype.js the Chromecast IOS bug is fixed.

Please does anyone know how I might solve this conundrum? 
Regards
Mark

Answer (score 1):

Magento 1.5.1.0 was the last to use Prototype 1.6.  Upgrade Magento to at least 1.6.0.0 and it will come with Prototype 1.7 and all necessary bug fixes to make it work.

Personally, I would try to upgrade all the way to Magento 1.9.0.1 for the peace of mind of having all security fixes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer. I found a workaround because i was using a custom template i loaded prototype 1.7 into  the specific template by changing the js link - now i dont need to upgrade. Though I would like to it is a long way back and costs are prohibitive for me

Comment: Please mark your answer as solution.